# What is a good way to use animation events to process melee attacks in Unity 3d?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

Okay so I'm working on like a hack and slash kind of game in Unity and I have an enemy object who I'd like have attack the player and deal damage using colliders. I have added an event to the enemy's attack animation that calls the function OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) that should deal the damage but I get a error saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" whenever I try it out. Does anyone have any ideas on how I could make this work?

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet can be very helpful for you to have an idea. I made this in an old project and works perfectly.

In this case is a right leg kick animation.

**NOTE**: code snippet not tested. “Health” script source is not included.

```
public class MeleeAttackController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SphereCollider kickAttackSphere; // in this case the sphere collider must be child of the right foot
    public float meleeAttackDamage = 50;
    public AudioClip kickAttackClip;

    CapsuleCollider m_capsule;

    void Awake()
    {
        kickAttackSphere.isTrigger = true;

        m_capsule = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
    }

    void Event_KickAttack_RightLeg() // invoked by the kick animation events (in case you have many kick animations)
    {
        if(CheckSphereAndApllyDamage(kickAttackSphere))
        {
            if (kickAttackClip)
            {
                AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(kickAttackClip, weaponAttackSphere.transform.position); // play the sound
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if the sphere collider overlap any collider with a health script. If overlap any collider also apply a the meleeAttackDamage.
    /// </summary>
    bool CheckSphereAndApllyDamage(SphereCollider sphere)
    {
        // check if we hit some object with a health script added
        Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(sphere.transform.position, sphere.radius, Physics.AllLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore);

        foreach (Collider collider in colliders)
        {
            if (collider == m_capsule) continue; // ignore myself

            Health health = collider.GetComponent<Health>();
            if (health)
            {
                // if the collider we overlap has a health, then apply the damage
                health.TakeDamage(meleeAttackDamage, transform);

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```